# Windows 10 SDK offline installer

Tags: windows, sdk, offline

Based on the question asked here: https://superuser.com/questions/1020732/windows-10-sdk-offline-installer?newreg=ee8cfc9d921e4923ab57443b31a3dc1f

I want to know how to link the downloaded SDK to my visual studio installation. I already have the sdk downloaded for offline but I still can't create new projects of universal apps in VS2015 community edition (update 2).
I'm trying to avoid having to install the sdk by ticking the option during VS installation cos it will fail due to no internet connection

My VS installation is from an iso image I downloaded from the office, where I also downloaded the standalone sdk.

Thanks.

Comment: Did u managed it?

Comment: I had to do a factory reset on my windows 10 installation. I ended up downloading the UWP tools online through VS installation, then I installed the offline downloaded standalone sdk.